flutter issue on android 14 after changing SDK version to 34
I have changed targetSdkVersion From 33 to 34 at build.gradle
but the app crashes on run, here's the logs
Exception:
D/AndroidRuntime( 7981): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981): Process: com.doubleclick.hre, PID: 7981
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981): java.lang.SecurityException: com.doubleclick.hre: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6157)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1853)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:772)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at com.jaumard.smsautofill.SmsAutoFillPlugin$2.onSuccess(SmsAutoFillPlugin.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at com.jaumard.smsautofill.SmsAutoFillPlugin$2.onSuccess(SmsAutoFillPlugin.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7981):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
I/Process ( 7981): Sending signal. PID: 7981 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

this problem at android 14. under this version android works well

you need to update gradle versions also

No, Just update sms_autofill Package Version. and app run normally

This issue is due to Android 14 (API level 34) enforcing stricter broadcast receiver permissions. In Android 14, when registering a receiver dynamically, you must explicitly declare either RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTD to specify if the receiver can handle broadcasts from outside your app.
To fix this, modify the AndroidManifest.xml where the broadcast receiver is declared, and ensure that you include one of these attributes depending on the requirement:
<receiver
    android:name="your.receiver.ClassName"
    android:exported="true" />  <!-- Set to false if it's internal -->

Or adjust it in your code when registering the receiver

thanks, I solve the problem by update sms_autofill Package Version. and app run normally
